# Authentication / authorization for different interfaces

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, wcf, authentication

I've got a Windows service where clients should be able to authenticate and authorize via different interfaces, but now I'm not sure what providers/classes/framework I should use.

Requirements on the security context:

- Users
- Groups
- Roles

Requirements on the authentication methods:

- Basic (username/password)
- Windows Login (current)
- Domain login
- Certificate

The interfaces my service provides:

- WCF host (WS-* conform)
- OWIN based Web API (for e.g. mobile devices)

Now Microsoft provides like a thousand ways to accomplish such a task with numerous classes, frameworks... from the new ASP.Net Identity Model to Forms Authentication to Security Context (WCF) or Principals (Windows) - what I'm looking for is a set of tools that can be used preferably everywhere (persisting in database, passing to WCF client proxies, using with view models in WPF..) What could I use so I don't have to spent the rest of my life mapping classes and data and doing heavy complex domain logic instead of taking advantage of a certain framework?

Answer (score 0):

ThinkTecture's excellent IdentityServer is probably the way to go. More information and downloads are [here](http://thinktecture.github.io/). Both build on the concept of federated authentication as provided by the [Windows Identity Foundation](http://www.microsoft.com/wif) (WIF) and [Active Directory Federation Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897402.aspx) (AD FS).

For blog posts on IdentityServer check out Dominick Baier's blog at [leastprivilege.com](http://leastprivilege.com/).

For more info on WIF and AD FS, Vittorio Bertocci has a [great book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627185). You can also download a copy of Microsoft's [Guide to Claims-Based Identity and Access Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423674.aspx).